# Can not unhide some bones

Tags: rigging

https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/78956#comment-114838

```
       I have to tweak this rig so I need to unhide bones in arms and legs. I've found them in the properties panel but Alt+H does not do any good.
```

[image: bones that can not be unhide]

Comment: Did you check bone layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the armature, go to properties/armature/bone layers and shift click on every layer to search all the bones of the skeleton. Uncheck the "shapes" option to turn off custom shapes.

[image]

Comment: I also found I had to change my view to default 3d for some reason bones were not visible in other windows such as animation due to visibility settings a trap for newbs like me!!
But very relieved I found them! thanks!